# SMTP and startssl jenkins exceptions

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, smtp, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure Jenkins in order to send mail notifications via my smtp server. It supports only SMTP over STARTTLS, so I tried to modify the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins config file adding, as suggested in many answers here on stackoverflow:

```
Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

I tried to add this option in

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS and/or JAVA_ARGS
```

Another thing I tried was to add the option:

```
-Dmail.smtp.ssl.enable=false
```

But no success at all.

I always get `invalid domain exception` or the `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?` depending on whether I disable/enable the use SSL option in the jenkins options.

I have also tried all these configurations, with all the combination of ports `(587, 465, 25..)` but it is always impossible to send a test mail.

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins uses the System Admin e-mail address as the sender address for e-mail notification.
You can configure this under Manage Jenkins → Configure System.